# Is each node call run its own version of node

Tags: javascript, node.js

If i run app by `node index.js` and then i do it again before the first process finishes. Do each call have it´s own separate nodejs instance with it´s own call stack?
What is the overheas of doing this?

Comment: Overhead, compared to doing what else?

Comment: Yes, it runs an entirely separate process.

Comment: Running just once instance as a server insted of calling index.js directly.

Comment: What do you mean by "running as a server"?

Comment: just try yourself, Ctrl+Shit+Escape and see the process list, fire up 2 instances, and see how many processed do you have... Works if you fire the "debug by attaching the nodeJs process", and you will see you have 2 different processes for each instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, each run gets its own process, you will not be able to link the processes in a normal way.
Furthermore, if both processes listen to the same port, the second run will fail with an error:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use

Comment: This would only happen if the node process is something that consumes a PORT on the machine. Usually happens when the app uses Express of some HTTP server dependency.